# How to get cpanel login url

Tags: php, cpanel

I am writing a WordPress plugin and I am using Guzzle library. I need to get cPanel login link. I can do this with 2083 or 2082 port, but some sites have closed these ports or shared hosting has a common cPanel login connection. I need to get the correct login link and send API requests. How can I get the correct login link?

Note:I didn't use cPanel live php because when i want to include the file i get fatal error. Cannot find cPanel class.

Comment: Make it configurable, and give it a default value (the most common).

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Are you suggesting that the cPanel login link should be entered by the user?

Comment: Almost. You use a default value, but it should be editable by the user, for when your default value isn't work.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP I thought about it but I want everything to be as automatic as possible. I need to get the cPanel login link programmatically.

Comment: Is not ussual, but it can be absolutely hidden, that's why I recommend to make it configurable. So, you can try /cpanel and :2083, maybe scan other ports, and save the first value that worked. If none worked, show an alert asking the user to update that option in your plugin.